# jquery script link is bug?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I insert this script link in my index.php

```js
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

It turns into this..

[image]

This is what it normaly look like and supposed to be look like

[image]

Here's the whole code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>
  <?php include ('title.php');?>
 </title>
 
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/LOGO.png"> 

 <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="assets/css/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="assets/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="assets/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 
 </head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <?php 
   session_start(); 
   include ("checkSession.php");
   include ("nav.php");
   include ("pagecontent.php");
  ?>
 </div>
 

 
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.3.2.min"></script>
 
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#listTable').DataTable();
  });
 </script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#print').DataTable({
        "paging":   false,
        "filter": false,
        "info":     false
    } );
  });
 </script>
 <script language="javascript">
 function Clickheretoprint()
 { 
   var disp_setting="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,"; 
    disp_setting+="scrollbars=yes,width=1000, height=400, left=100, top=25"; 
   var content_vlue = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML; 
   
   var docprint=window.open("","",disp_setting); 
    docprint.document.open(); 
    docprint.document.write('</head><body onLoad="self.print()" style="width: 1500px; font-size:11px; font-family:arial; font-weight:normal;">');          
    docprint.document.write(content_vlue); 
    docprint.document.close(); 
    docprint.focus(); 
 }


 </script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
  </script>

 




</body>

</html>
```

Well If I remove the script link and put in the other source code, It doesn't work so I really need that script link to run the function :(

Answer (score 3):

You've double (actually, triple) included jQuery.

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.3.2.min"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

It's likely some stuff in your jQuery 1.3.2-compatible code doesn't work in jQuery 1.10.2 (which as the last version loaded, overrides the others). Check your console for script errors.

You can use multiple versions of jQuery on a page using [jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) but you'd really be better off solving the more fundamental issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now, I just need to edit  it into

```js
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe it's because of the protocol used to access the CDN of jquery. Try this instead:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

if that doesn't work, try with HTTPS:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```